# how to style jquery sortable target list before drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

Using jquery sortable i can style a placeholder inside a conect list defined in `connectWith` option, so i can see where content will be dropped.
However i can't find a way to style the list which contains the placeholder.

My code:

HTML:

```
<div class="sortable">
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="sortable"></div>
<div class="sortable"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable",
    over: function(event,ui){
        //add class .hover to list
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        //style placeholder
        ui.placeholder.css({
            visibility: 'visible',
            background: '#EEE'
        });
    }
});
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/quakeglen/km0sw55t/)

Comment: Did you solve your issue ?

Comment: Still working on minimized code, is addClass function really needed?

Comment: It is not. It is a way to aerate the code :)

Comment: Did my answer helped you?  If yes, can you check it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Alteyss's answer i have styled item parent's by adding a new line on events over, stop and out:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable",
    stop: function(event,ui){
        $('.sortable').removeClass('hover');
    },
    over: function(event,ui){
        //will add class .hover to list
        $('.ui-sortable-placeholder').parents('.sortable').addClass('hover');
    },
    out: function(event,ui){
        $('.ui-sortable-placeholder').parents('.sortable').removeClass('hover');
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        //will style placeholder
        $('.ui-sortable-placeholder').css({
            visibility: 'visible',
            background: '#EEE'
        });
    }
});
```

[New Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/quakeglen/km0sw55t/3/)

Answer (score 1):

**An other way to change the `placeholder` style :**

See you have (when you drag your box) a tag with a class related to the placeholder :

```
ui-sortable-placeholder
```

So make a class that will override the presets :

```
.ui-sortable-placeholder
{
  //Style
}
```

**Edit: Applicate the hover class**

Create a function that handle your `hover` class in jQuery and call it into the event parameters:

```
    // Your function
    var addClass = function (jQueryElement, add) {
        // Add or remove your class according to the boolean
        if (add) {
            //Add class with : addClass from jQuery
            $(jQueryElement).addClass("hover");
        } 
        else {
            //Remove class with : removeClass from jQuery
            $(jQueryElement).removeClass("hover");
        }
    }

    // Plugin use
    $(".sortable").sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortable",
        // This event is triggered when a sortable item is moved into a sortable list.
        over: function(event,ui){
            var elementsToChange = $(".ui-sortable-placeholder").parents(".sortable");
            addClass(elementsToChange, true);
        },
        // This event is triggered when a sortable item is moved away from a sortable list.
        out: function(event,ui){
            var elementsToChange = $(".ui-sortable-placeholder").parents(".sortable");
            addClass(elementsToChange, false);
        },
        // This event is triggered when sorting has stopped.
        stop: function(event,ui){
            addClass(".sortable", false);
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            //style placeholder
            ui.placeholder.css({
                visibility: 'visible',
                background: '#EEE'
            });
        }
    });
```

[Beautiful Fiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/Alteyss/dx73mh36/)

**For other events, enjoy the DOC :** http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Still only styles placeholder

Comment: Indeed! I made the changes, hope it will be useful.